# Does the presence of a Content-ID header in an email MIME mean that the attachment must be embedded?

Tags: email, mime, rfc

Two different third-party email products we have are reacting differently to the presence of a **content-id** header in the MIME source of an email. This is resulting in an inconsistent user experience that we're trying to resolve.

Here's an example:

```
--boundary-example
Content-Location: CID:somethingatelse 
Content-ID: <foo4atfoo1atbar.net>
Content-Type: IMAGE/GIF
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

R0lGODlhGAGgAPEAAP/////ZRaCgoAAAACH+PUNv
cHlyaWdodCAoQykgMTk5LiBVbmF1dGhvcml6ZWQgZHV
wbGljYXRpb24gcHJvaGliaXRlZC4A etc..
```

One email product interprets this as an embedded image.  The other interprets this as an ordinary attachment (not embedded).  If we completely remove the **Content-ID** line, both products think the attachment is not embedded.

Is there a specific RFC that definitively concludes which behavior is correct?  A colleague and I reviewed RFC2392 which in the opening abstract says:

> The use of [MIME] within email to convey Web pages and their
>   associated images requires a URL scheme to permit the HTML to refer
>   to the images or other data included in the message.  The Content-ID
>   Uniform Resource Locator, "cid:", serves that purpose. […] The "cid"
>   scheme refers to a specific body part of a    message; its use is
>   generally limited to references to other body    parts in the same
>   message as the referring body part.  The "mid"    scheme may also
>   refer to a specific body part within a designated    message, by
>   including the content-ID's address.

So, while not absolute, we're inclined to believe that since all embedded items need a cid to reference them, and that it is “generally limited to other body parts in the same message,” and that attachments *don’t* need a cid, it is reasonable behavior for an email product to treat the presence of a cid, as an indicator of “intent to embed”.

Can I get confirmation on this?

Comment: ask RFC author or relevant IETF WG, maybe?

Answer (score 9):

The `Content-ID` does not indicate that a image should be displayed inline. This header is needed to reference the embedded data within HTML.

As an email is a text-message there is no reason to display an image embedded, as long as the mail is plain-text.

Some clients does display the data inline regardless of the format is HTML or plain-text. But this is not a defined behaveior

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for the `Content-Disposition` header field, which allows you define the presentation style of a body part (such as an image) to be `inline` or `attachment`.

Here's an inline example created by Thunderbird:

```
--------------040202010204080305090405
Content-Type: image/png; name="test.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.02080004.04000407@sample.com>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.png"
```

You can read more at:

- The RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183
- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition

Comment: Content-Disposition header is not always included. Sometimes it is needed to derive whether a part is inline or an attachment based on the headers provided in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here what would be my approach to this.

**If you are a sender**

Always add a `Content-Disposition` header to your attachment. Either by indicating inline or attachment, with the filename. Such as:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.png"` or `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.png"`

This will remove any ambiguity.

**If you are a parser/receiver**

1. First, consider all attachments as *not inline*.
2. If the attachment has a content-id, consider it inline.
3. Then, if the attachment has a content-disposition, respect the disposition indicated.

By doing so that way, you'll ensure that the content-disposition (last check) is always respected, but by default you treat attachments as external except when a CID is provided.

This works well for most of the emails sent.